# Restriction on pages after login in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, routes, react-router

So I'm using react router v6 in my React App.

I have the following routes enabled in my app.js file

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/' component={<Home />} />
   <Route path='/login' component={<SignUp />} />
   <Route path='/signup' component={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

Everything's fine and that. What I want to to do is to put restriction on pages. Now  I know how to create PrivateRoutes and PublicRoutes based on LoggedIn User.

For this purpose I want the user to not be able to access Homepage after he or she signups.

Are there an functions for that or what strategy would I use.

Comment: if you want to redirect from one route to another, you can check auth status in component did mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this using 'react-router-dom' and creating a PrivateRoute component. The following code is not tested but can give you some ideas. LoaderComponent is a loading animation of your choice can be toher component as well.

```js
// Based on https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow
// If the user is not yet authenticated.
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children, path, ...props }) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        //put your authentication logic
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }, []);

    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...props}
            render={() => (isAuthenticated ? children : <LoaderComponent />)}
        />
    );
};
```

And in your router config

```js
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/'>
         <Home />
    </PrivateRoute>
    ...
</Switch>
```